# Import and export csv with json

Tags: python, json, csv

I want to use the PTV API for reverse geocoding of GPS coordinates.

I have latitudes and longitudes and I want to have complete addresses.

I have a script that can do it line by line. I want to be able to automate the script and be able to geocode a csv file and export the result in csv as well.

as I do not master neither python nor json, I have trouble adapting the script.

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json


def main():
    # JSON Data
    payload = {
        "location": {
            "coordinate": {
                "point": {
                    "x": 2.35257,
                    "y": 48.83592
                }
            }
        },
        "options": [],
        "sorting": [],
        "additionalFields": [],
        "callerContext": {
            "properties": [
                {
                    "key": "Profile",
                    "value": "default"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    jsonData = json.dumps(payload)
    header = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

    token = ''
    # Accessing the xServer internet API
    jsonresp = requests.post(
        url='http://localhost:50020/xlocate/rs/XLocate/findLocation', data=jsonData, headers=header, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('xtok', token))
    # In Python 3.5 use: 'resp = json.loads(str(jsonresp.text))

    resp = jsonresp.json()

    print(resp)
    for result in resp['resultList']:
        print(result['postCode'] + ';' + result['country'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? Could you also post a sample of your CSV and an expected output?

Comment: welcome here ! what does print(resp) show to you ?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#index-0 about reading and writing csv files. The idea is to use payload as a 'template' and replace the point values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to read/write csv files.

```
payload = {
        "location": {
            "coordinate": {
                "point": {
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": 0
                }
            }
        },
        "options": [],
        "sorting": [],
        "additionalFields": [],
        "callerContext": {
            "properties": [
                {
                    "key": "Profile",
                    "value": "default"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

results = []
# assuming the list below is coming from a csv file
geo_points = [[2.3,48.7],[2.56,47.12],[2.55,48.00]]
for point in geo_points:
    payload['location']['coordinate']['point']['x'] = point[0]
    payload['location']['coordinate']['point']['y'] = point[1]
    # now you can do the HTTP call and get the data from the server
    # keep the result in a list or dict so that by the end of the loop
    # you will be able to write it to csv
```